# Commonjs resource path of Titanium mobile

Tags: javascript, android, titanium-mobile, commonjs, titanium-modules

I have a project which have following folder structure

```
Resources/
  android/
    images/
      res-hdpi/
        main.png
      res-mdpi/
        main.png
      res-ldpi/
        main.png
  iphone/
    images/
  images/
    main.png
    main@2x.png
  ui/
    MainView.js
```

MainView.js is writing in commonjs fashion

```
    function MainView()
    {
     var self = Ti.UI.createImageView({

                height : '25dp',
                width : '25dp',
                image : 'images/main.png'
            });

    return self;
    }

module.exports = MainView;
```

Those code perform as expacted in iOS but not the same story in Android.
I expected in high resolution device, it will load android/images/res-hdpi/main.png as a image but it keeps saying path not found.

I am using Titanium SDK 1.8.2

Comment: It will always point to Resources/images.

Comment: If I change the path '/images/main.png' instead of 'images/main.png', it will always point to Resources/images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you ever resolved this or not, but your tiapp.xml file has state that your application supports these densities.  Also, after adding the images to /android/images, you have to clean the project to force a rebuild.  The build process indexes the images and creates a resource file with the file name and an integer value (which is also why the file name cannot start with a number).

Comment: Clean build help to my issue.It is resoloved and I am not in SDK 1.8.2 now.